# Multiple antiderivatives?

Tags: calculus, integration

The way I have seen the fundamental theorem of calculus stated is:

$$\int_a^bf(x)\ dx=F(b)-F(a)$$

Where $F(x)$ is **any antiderivative** of $f(x)$. Does the "any antiderivative" refer to the constant $C$ that is always added to the integral, or are there functions that have several completely different antiderivatives?

Comment: Yes, it's the constant. If $F' \equiv G'$, then $(F-G)' = 0$, so $F - G$ is constant (on any interval where $F$ and $G$ are defined).

Comment: Its a corollary of the MVT, that all derivatives will only differ by a constant, so the most general form will be $F(x)+C$.

Comment: @daniel If you do this, then you are assuming that $f\equiv0$ has a unique antiderivative up to a constant factor, wich is what you want to prove...

Comment: @gebruiker The mean value theorem of differential calculus doesn't even know what a primitive (an antiderivative) is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, your first hunch is right. "Any" antiderivative refers to the fact that an antiderivate is really a family of functions which differ only by a constant.